# Angular5 Email autocomplete/mailchecker

Tags: angular

I am trying to have email suggestions/checker with Angular5. I could find in angularjs  [mailchecker](https://github.com/simison/angular-mailcheck) , [mailchecker.js](https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck/)but not in Angular5.

Suppose in the input box, user puts, developer then it should show do you mean:- developer@gmail.com

user input:- developer@hotnail.com, it should show do you mean :- developer@hotmail.com

user input:- developer@flldkld , it should show do you mean:- developer@edu

I have tried to achieve and tried to find some third party libraries but couldnt find anything so far

Below is the working stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-formss?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You can easily add mailchecker to your angular project, and use it combined with jquery or not. You just need a `@ViewChild` to catch the element

Comment: combined with jquery?

Comment: Yes, that library uses Jquery selectors to catch the email input, and then adds the functionallity of emailchecker `$("#email").mailcheck` this works fine with angular, check this out [How to add Jquery plugin on Angular](https://medium.com/all-is-web/angular-5-using-jquery-plugins-5edf4e642969)

Comment: I dont know whether its best practice or not

Comment: Also, I never done that, can you update the stackblitz if possible?

Comment: Mmm in that case, the best would be use the Javascript version of that library, adding `Mailcheck.run` as a object to your Angular project

Comment: Done i've updated your stackblitz!

Comment: may i get the link? I think you need to fork my project and then need to give me new link

Comment: Here you go [link](https://angular-reactive-formss-4g1apr.stackblitz.io)

Comment: I am sorry its not working, can I see your code? I am trying from my end too but its not working

Comment: I already did email validation using emailvalidator I can see only that from your link.

Comment: my bad, post the wrong link  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-formss-4g1apr)

Comment: The code is implemented but its not responding, i meant not giving suggestions for email

Comment: it throws an alert if you misspell something according to the suggestions, for example: usermail@gnail.cmo

Comment: not to me, its not responding anything

Comment: okay it works partially sorry.

Comment: Any error?, i've added `typings.d.ts` file and modified `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: yeah, it didnt pass the test cases which I have, like in the question, user input:- kdjjk@lkl, it should show in error do you mean:- kdjjk@edu not on submit,.... like now if you dont write @ then it says enter valid email

Comment: Yeah the reex pattern that uses, isn't very precise